# Javascript Google Protobuf Library

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I have used Google's protoc compiler to create javascript classes out of my protobufs.

How do I give them data?

The docs mention a .deserializeBinary(data) method, but that doesn't seem to be present on any of the classes generated?

Passing binary directly into the constructor seems to make an object filled with binary junk.

Comment: There should be a `deserializeBinary` method; if one's not being generated could you post the `protoc` command you're using and the generated JavaScript that results?

Comment: Yep, missing a compiler flag was the problem.  IMHO generating those methods should be the default behavior and the flag should be to turn it off, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protoc` does not, by default, generate the deserializeBinary method.  You must pass `protoc` the `binary` option to make it generate deserializeBinary.

Google 'recommends' but does not require this option to be enabled...

Comment: What is the form should of the data passed to deserializeBinary?  I have a remote server sending me data as a DataView, but passing that to deserializeBinary doesn't seem to work at all.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The form of the data will vary depending on the protobuf you have.  Unfortunately I can't help you without knowing an awful lot more about the specifics of your situation

Comment: Figured it out.  Can't pass object of type DataView to deserializeBinary function.  Need to convert DataView to a binary array first, then pass that array to deserializeBinary, then use the protobuf generated functions on the deserialized object to extract information.